# Multiplicative monoids of polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

By computing the multiplicative monoids decide if either of the rings are fields and in each case identify the unit group as an abstract group.

i) $F_3[x]/(x^2+2x+2)$

ii) $F_3[x]/(x^2+2)$

I know how to construct multiplication tables to solve this problem, but the only idea I have of what monoids are, is from the definitions I can look up online and that hasn't helped me in finding a way to solve the problem. I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: It looks like what they want you to do is to compute the multiplication table - I can't imagine what "computing the multiplicative monoid" means otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For the second $(x+1)(x+2)= x^2+2x+x+2=x^2+2$ in $F_3[x]$ so the class of $x+1$ is a divisor of zero in $Z_3[x]/(x^2+2)$.

You can check that the invertible elements are the class of $1,2,x,2x$ since the order of these elements is $2$, the group of unity is $Z_2\times Z_2$.

The first one is a field, you can see this by computing the multiplication table, or by remarking that $x^2+2x+2$ does not have a root in $Z_3$. (Just test $0,1,2$). Thus $F_3[x]/(x^2+2x+2)$ is an extension of degree $2$ of $Z_3$, it has $9$ elements and a classical result says that its group of units is $Z/8$.

Comment: Thanks, that really cleared it up. The only part I have left is classifying the unit group of ii as an abstract group. I found it to be a group of size 4 and I was wondering if there is a fast way to classify it.

Comment: In this case I found it to be $C_2 X C_2$ fairly quickly, but would still be interesting to know if there is a shortcut for more complex cases